# Solve $z^4 = 1$ for all $z$ , Hence or otherwise, solve $z^4 =(z-1)^4$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> > Question: Solve $z^4 = 1$ for all $z$.
> >
> > Hence or otherwise, solve $z^4 =(z-1)^4$.

---

My attempt for the first part

$$z^4 = 1$$

$$z^4 -1 =0$$

$$ (z^2-1)(z^2+1) = 0 $$

$$ (z-1)(z+1)(z+i)(z=i)=0$$

$$ z = 1,-1,i,-i$$

However I am stuck on the second part , what hint does the first part give to solve the second part. I'm referring to the "otherwise".

---

I think I get the second part now

$$z^4 =(z-1)^4$$

$$ z^4  - (z-1)^4 = 0 $$

Let p = z , q = (z-1)

$$ p^4 - q^4 = 0 $$

$$ (p^2-q^2)(p^2+q^2)=0 $$

$$ (p-q)(p+q)(p^2+q^2)=0 $$

$$ (z-(z-1))(z+(z-1))(z^2+(z-1)^2) = 0 $$

$$ (1)(2z-1)(z^2 + z^2 - 2z + 1) = 0 $$

$$ (2z-1)(2z^2 -2z +1)=0$$

$$ z = \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1+i}{2} , \frac{1-i}{2} $$

However am I suppose to get 4 solutions not 3?

Comment: What do you mean by "Hence or otherwise", is the first statement supposed to imply the second, or are these two separate problems you are trying to solve?

Comment: the first statement is supposed to imply the second (they are part of one whole question)

Comment: Okay, then I think there is a typo or something, because none of the solutions to the first equality work for the second.

Comment: I think it has to do with the method of solving? .. I'm not too sure

Comment: Divide each side by $(z-1)^4 $

Comment: You won't get four solutions because $z^4-(z-1)^4$ is a cubic polynomial, and hence can have only three roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely correct on the first question so let's work on the second one.

We can divide both sides by $(z-1)^4$.  We now have to find the solutions to the equation ${z^4 \over(z-1)^4} = 1$ or $({z\over z-1})^4 = 1$.  Take the 4th root of both sides and you get $1^{1/4} = {z \over (z-1)}$.  There are a couple of possible answers for $1^{1/4}$.  $1, -1, i, -i$ specifically.  Now all you have to do is find the specific solutions for each of the branches.  I'll leave the algebra to you as I'm pretty sure you can do it from here.

One of the roots above doesn't end up working because of what we did to the domain.  $1 = {z \over (z-1)}$ doesn't have a solution because it implies that $z-1 = z$ or that $-1 = 0$.  We have to discard this root so we are left with three roots.

Comment: Thank you for that , I was also wondering could I use difference of two squares for the second one as well?

Comment: I don't think so.  You could expand the right hand side of the equation and subtract z^2 and get a cubic but that is way more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: On second thought I'm not right.  You can use difference of squares to find the roots and that would work just fine.  It might be a bit more difficult because you have to solve two quadratics but it's still pretty easy.

Comment: Can you check my edit please and answer why I do not get 4 roots?

Comment: One of the branches ends up not working.  I'll edit that in but there are only three roots.